Making TabBarView take up the remainder of the Screen
I want to display TabBar in a screen point in which it take the remaining space of the screen. While doing that, I aim to display two GridViews in a two tabs of that TabBar
When I use an Expanded Widget it causes the app the crash, it only works if I use a SizedBox with height constraints.
Here is the code
import 'package:bespoked_1_1/utils/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class SellersHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SellersHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<SellersHomePage> createState() => _SellersHomePageState();
}

class _SellersHomePageState extends State<SellersHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Epoxy Forever'),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.ios_share,
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.shopping_cart_outlined,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Stack(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: screenHeight * 0.3,
                width: screenWidth,
                child: ShaderMask(
                  shaderCallback: (rect) {
                    return LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      colors: const [Colors.black, Colors.transparent],
                    ).createShader(
                        Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, rect.width, rect.height));
                  },
                  blendMode: BlendMode.dstIn,
                  child: Image(
                    fit: BoxFit
                        .cover, //TODO: Give the option to change the fit of the image
                    height: screenHeight * 0.2,
                    image: NetworkImage(
                        'https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/carpenter-cutting-mdf-board-inside-workshop_23-2149451051.jpg'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              //sellers logo and details
              Positioned(
                top: 20,
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: const [
                      //profile image
                      CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 50,
                        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                            'https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/37/76/72/360_F_137767250_pocwIHgKu5rDuYFDNCTNcPy77gHb1lfh.jpg'),
                      ),

                      //name
                      Text(
                        'Karls Carpentry',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 24),
                      ),

                      //sub heading
                      Text(
                        'Specialist in Fine custom furniture and upholstery',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),

          //business stats
          Center(
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25), color: Colors.grey),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 10),
              child: const Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  //avg rating
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        '4.8',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                      ),
                      Text('Avg Rating')
                    ],
                  ),

                  //followers
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        '28',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                      ),
                      Text('Avg Rating')
                    ],
                  ),

                  //callouts and items sold
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        '200',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                      ),
                      Text('Avg Rating')
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),

          DefaultTabController(
            length: 3,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                //tabs
                TabBar(indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab, tabs: [
                  Tab(
                    text: 'Shop',
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    text: 'Posts',
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    text: 'About',
                  ),
                ]),

                //tabviews
                TabBarView(children: [
                  Icon(Icons.shop),
                  Icon(Icons.image),
                  Icon(Icons.info)
                ])
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


Try the following, it's your code but added what you want.
To make the TabBar allocate the remaining space of the screen, wrap it with Expanded widget.
Also, there are two tabs with that hold a scrollable Grid layout:
class SellersHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SellersHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<SellersHomePage> createState() => _SellersHomePageState();
}

class _SellersHomePageState extends State<SellersHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Epoxy Forever'),
          centerTitle: true,
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.ios_share,
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.shopping_cart_outlined,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Stack(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: screenHeight * 0.3,
                  width: screenWidth,
                  child: ShaderMask(
                    shaderCallback: (rect) {
                      return LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        colors: const [Colors.black, Colors.transparent],
                      ).createShader(
                          Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, rect.width, rect.height));
                    },
                    blendMode: BlendMode.dstIn,
                    child: Image(
                      fit: BoxFit
                          .cover, //TODO: Give the option to change the fit of the image
                      height: screenHeight * 0.2,
                      image: NetworkImage(
                          'https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/carpenter-cutting-mdf-board-inside-workshop_23-2149451051.jpg'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                //sellers logo and details
                Positioned(
                  top: 20,
                  left: 0,
                  right: 0,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: const [
                        //profile image
                        CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 50,
                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                              'https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/37/76/72/360_F_137767250_pocwIHgKu5rDuYFDNCTNcPy77gHb1lfh.jpg'),
                        ),

                        //name
                        Text(
                          'Karls Carpentry',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 24),
                        ),

                        //sub heading
                        Text(
                          'Specialist in Fine custom furniture and upholstery',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),

            //business stats
            Center(
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25), color: Colors.grey),
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 10),
                child:  Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    //avg rating
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          '4.8',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                        ),
                        Text('Avg Rating')
                      ],
                    ),

                    //followers
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          '28',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                        ),
                        Text('Avg Rating')
                      ],
                    ),

                    //callouts and items sold
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          '200',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                        ),
                        Text('Avg Rating')
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),

            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  //tabs
                  TabBar(indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab, tabs: [
                    Tab(
                      text: 'Shop',
                    
                    ),
                    Tab(
                      text: 'Posts',
                    ),
                    Tab(
                      text: 'About',
                    ),
                  ]),

                  //tabviews
                  Expanded(
                    child: TabBarView(children: [
                      GridView.builder(
                        itemBuilder: (context,index)=>Container(color: Colors.yellow),
                        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: 3,
                          crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                        ),
                      ),
                      

                      GridView.builder(
                        itemBuilder: (context,index)=>Container(color: Colors.purple),
                        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: 3,
                          crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Icon(Icons.info)
                    ]),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

First Tab

Second Tab

Note: Tabs are underlined with the blue solid line, but their labels needs styling, handle it in your theme.

Thank you, do you not need to have a Default Tab Controller then for it to work?

@TheSynergist no, TabBar needs a controller to manage its navigation of tabs. The answer has a DefaultTabController directly above the scaffold.
